# Masstransit RabbitMq Auto-delete quorum queue

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Is it possible to auto-delete a QuorumQueue in RabbitMQ? I am using MassTransit and can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas why or how I can achieve it?

```
                config.ReceiveEndpoint(settings.RabbitMq.CommandName + "-" + settings.ServiceId, e => {
                    e.AutoDelete = true;
                    e.Durable = true;
                    e.ConfigureConsumer<ModelA>(context);
                    e.SetQuorumQueue();
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might [read the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html) to understand the differences between Quorum queues and regular queues, but they are extensive.

Specifically, they can *only* be durable, and are *not* meant to be temporary.

Oh, they also **require** a quorum to operate, which is at least 2 of 3 nodes.

Comment: +1 And "temporary" means among other things _not_ [auto-deleted](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#temporary-queues)